# explain ip address terminology used

Tags: ip-address

I'm trying figure out the terminology used when describing ip address **so I can write a C# application**

Does anyone know what the slash mean? In some places I see for example

```
1.0.231.0/24
```

Does this means a range from 1.0.231.0 - 1.0.231.24?

On various Icann documents they refer to

```
255.255.255.255/32
```

I am not sure how that can be a range

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing

Comment: The /<number> is how a computer can quickly calculate what is part of its network and what is not. It represents the bit length of the subnet mask.

Comment: Off topic? seriously moderator dudes, software does not exist in isolation. without understanding the underlying data structures and meanings, software is pointless and useless. Updated question now, it says C#. hope you are all happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I look at it like this. The number after the slash is how many bits in the ip address that identify your network. For example:

For Ipv4, Ip addresses are 32 bits in length. Using your example we have the following:

1.0.231.0 = 32 bits

convert that to binary we get: **00000001.00000000.11100111**.00000000

so the first 24 bits (in bold) is your identifier for the network assigned to you. the remaining 8 bits are what get assigned to your devices locally.

For your phone: 1.0.231.1
For your laptop: 1.0.231.3
For your desktop: 1.0.231.23 and so on up to 255.

Comment: Thanks for that, so does this mean that the number after the slash should always be even or can it be odd?

Comment: I'm not sure for practical uses, but hypothetically it could be anything up to 32.